# Subscribe to newsletter dialog missing a submit button

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter, popups, homepage

When viewing the homepage of a site without being logged in, we see such box in the right sidebar:

> [image]

Clicking "Sign up for the newsletter" brings a dialog that currently looks like this:

> [image]

As you can see, no submit button. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will submit the form, but not everyone knows that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stumbled upon that one by myself, more details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247946/156631)