# Newsletter registration email field has missized placeholder overlay

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, newsletter

I visited a question [posted on the Stack Exchange Google+ account](https://plus.google.com/u/0/101120115153580954446/posts/FaW2hfwxjSV) and happened to get the newsletter registration prompt, which appears to have a styling issue in the email field:

[image: newsletter prompt with wonky email field]

The quick fix would be for the two fields to just have the same width (149px vs 200px), but it probably also makes sense at this point to just do away with the pseudo placeholders and just use the `placeholder` attribute universally, with a polyfill for legacy browsers.

Comment: I was about to ask the same question just now and found this question..this issue I could reproduce on [foodSafety](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eTdLw.png) , [CodeGolf](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BrUPm.png) but [Information Security](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L49nJ.png) seems OK

Comment: Repo on Travel and Workplace, Chrome latest version, [Also on Firefox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229436/in-question-newsletter-signup-box-misaligned). :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the placeholder being on the submit (which caught my interest in the first place, and got me looking at other newsletter subscription paths), the anonymous newsletter subscription code was broken even [harder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209893/subscribe-to-newsletter-dialog-missing-a-submit-button). All those subscription forms now have a placeholder only (no custom overlay), which solves a lot of related design bugs as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looked at the code.

```
<form id="anon-newsletter-form">
    <input type="email" class="actual-edit-overlay" style="opacity: 1; position: absolute; color: black; -webkit-text-fill-color: black; width: 149px; height: 16px; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; text-align: start; border: 2px inset rgb(136, 136, 136); background-color: white;" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="email" id="newsletter-email-input" class="" style="opacity: 1; z-index: 1; position: relative;">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" placeholder="email address" id="newsletter-email-submit">            
</form>
```

It looks like they have two boxes to give it an effect... I don't know why they don't use CSS. They most likely can accomplish the same thing in pure CSS.

### EDIT:

It seems to be fixed now, can anyone repo this?

> [image]