# In-Question newsletter signup box misaligned

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

While browsing questions earlier today, I noticed the newsletter signup form that sometimes appears in the answer list of a question has a subtle input box that is misaligned relative to the more visible "email address" box beneath it that acts as a label. A freehand circle for reference:
[image: These boxes should be aligned]
[image: Does not look right]

Firefox 28.0 on Windows 7 Professional, 64 bit.

Comment: Ick, it's even worse than before!